# How to handle elm mdl indexes in a big single page application?

Tags: elm

This is an example from elm-mdl

```elm
Button.render Mdl [0] model.mdl
  [ Button.raised
  , Button.ripple
  , Button.onClick PollMsg
  ]
  [ text "Fetch new"]
```

Index here is [0]. I assume if I am building a single page application I can put indexes like ["page0", 0]. Is that right?

But does that mean that all the mdl data for all the buttons in the application is in memory? How is it working?

Comment: ["page0", 0] will not work since you have to specify a list of Integers. Since mdl-models do not hold that much of information they are not likely a problem regarding memory-usage. the models are mostly used to hold animation-state, so it's likely ok to reuse indexes on different pages. a neat trick is to use List.indexedMap when mapping a collection. this way you get an index for every item (as in `Button.render Mdl [0, i] model.mdl`).

Answer (score 5):

elm-mdl uses these identifiers for its internal handling. In particular, these ids are the reason you can get away with such simple calls to `update` and `view`.

As @pierrebeitz already explained, these integers reside in the application memory, but that's not a problem (even if you had hundreds of buttons).

As for working with elm-mdl in larger contexts, you have at least these two options available:

1. Use a number-combination like `[0, 0], [0, 1]` and so on. This is particularly useful, if you generate multiple similar elm-mdl components (f.ex. radio buttons or such) in a loop. In your code, the first index may be hard-coded, but the second integers stem from the looping.
2. For the overall picture you need to keep in mind, that these integers are local to your actual elm-mdl Model instance. In other words, creating a separate Model allows you to re-use these integers. This means you can use TEA components where a component has its own model, including an elm-mdl Model. As each component has free reign over the identifiers it uses, you have an easier time not to mess them up.

All that being said, I consider these indexes the worst part of elm-mdl. I would really appreciate if they could get rid of them (without overly complicating the resulting code of course), but for the time being I consider them the price tag for an otherwise awesome material design library.